# I want to use order by with multiple queries which are using intersect keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
select * from customer intersect 

select * from customer where lower(name) = 'ans' intersect

select * from customer where mobile_num='4777899456'

order by name;
```

//This query returns >ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your current query as an inline view, and apply `ORDER BY` to the enclosing `SELECT`, such as

```
  SELECT *
    FROM (-- current query starts here
          SELECT * FROM customer
          INTERSECT
          SELECT * FROM customer WHERE LOWER (name) = 'ans'
          INTERSECT
          SELECT * FROM customer WHERE mobile_num = '4777899456'
          -- current query ends here
         )
ORDER BY name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use `intersect` for this?  All the table references are to the same table, so all the rows in the result set have to have all the same columns.

I think this does what you want:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where lower(name) = 'ans' and
      mobile_num = '4777899456'
order by name;
```

You may want `select distinct`.

Comment: I wanted to use the query in a swing application where one can search based on no or combination of fields hence this solution wont work.